Customized output when referencing autonumbered paragraph
I have a customized paragraph that I use to define skills and autonumber them. When referencing the paragraphs, the output should be custom text plus counter number (e.g., S1, S2 etc). But currently, only the number is printed.
What am I doing wrong in my approach?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcounter{skillCounter}
\newcommand{\skillParagraph}[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{skillCounter}%
    \paragraph*{#1 (S\arabic{skillCounter})}%
    \label{#2}%
    \expandafter\def\csname customlabel@#2\endcsname{#1 (S\theskillCounter)}%
}

% Custom command to reference custom labels
\newcommand{\cparref}[1]{%
    \hyperref[#1]{\csname customlabel@#1\endcsname}%
}

\begin{document}
\section*{Skills}

\skillParagraph{Maths}{skill:maths} You should know maths.
\skillParagraph{Latex}{skill:latex} You should know \LaTeX.

You need skills \ref{skill:maths} and \ref{skill:latex}.

\skillParagraph{Word}{skill:word} You should know Word.

You need skills \ref{skill:maths}, \ref{skill:latex}, and \ref{skill:word}.

\end{document}



You should define a representation for the counter. And better put the \refstepcounter inside the paragraph, so that the anchor can not be separated from the heading.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcounter{skillCounter}
\renewcommand\theskillCounter{S\arabic{skillCounter}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\skillParagraph}[2]{%%
    \paragraph*{%
      \refstepcounter{skillCounter}%
      \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#1 (\theskillCounter)}%
      \label{#2}%
      #1 (\theskillCounter)}%%
}
\makeatother
% Custom command to reference custom labels
\newcommand{\cparref}[1]{\nameref{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Skills}

\skillParagraph{Maths}{skill:maths} You should know maths.
\skillParagraph{Latex}{skill:latex} You should know \LaTeX.

You need skills \ref{skill:maths} and \ref{skill:latex}.

\skillParagraph{Word}{skill:word} You should know Word.

You need skills \ref{skill:maths}, \ref{skill:latex}, and \ref{skill:word}.

\nameref{skill:maths}
\end{document}


So slow.... :-)

Thanks! Could you add some comments to the code? I don't even understand my own code...


What am I doing wrong in my approach?

I'd say two things. First, what you describe as expected results, apparently, are supposed to be the result of your custom reference command \cparref, but then you refer to everything with the standard \ref, which of course just references to the number, as expected. Second, and more fundamental, \cparref is defined in a way it can only be used after the \skillParagraph which creates the label, and this is not quite what a cross-reference is (normally) supposed to do. Besides, your \cparref seems to be just reinventing the wheel of nameref, so why not just use what you already have?
\documentclass{article}

% utf8 has been the default inputenc for some years now
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}

\newcounter{skillCounter}
% You could instead hard-code the S into \skillParagraph, as you've been
% doing, or define an \autoref prefix, etc.  This just seems to get a
% reasonable default value for \ref (affects any cross-reference to the
% counter though).
\renewcommand{\theskillCounter}{S\arabic{skillCounter}}
\newcommand{\skillParagraph}[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{skillCounter}%
    \paragraph*{#1 (\theskillCounter)}%
    \label{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\section*{Skills}

\skillParagraph{Maths}{skill:maths} You should know maths.
\skillParagraph{Latex}{skill:latex} You should know \LaTeX.

You need skills \ref{skill:maths} and \ref{skill:latex}.

Note that \ref{skill:word} and \nameref{skill:word} work before the
corresponding skill paragraph.

\skillParagraph{Word}{skill:word} You should know Word.

You need skills \ref{skill:maths}, \ref{skill:latex}, and \ref{skill:word}.

And, for whatever you wanted \texttt{\textbackslash{}cparref} to do, just use
\texttt{\textbackslash{}nameref}: \nameref{skill:maths},
\nameref{skill:latex}, and \nameref{skill:word}.


\end{document}



Thanks, but there is still a flaw: In the second paragraph, Latex (S2), there is a counter error in the second line. Note that "S3" and "Word (S2)" -- the counters don't match, although they both refer to skill:word.

@mike Oops, fixed that.

Thank you very much!
